# How to create a new instance of a class with a certain constructor dynamically

Tags: java

package company;

```
public abstract class A {
    public A(int i) {}
    public abstract void func();

}

public class B extends A {
   public B(int i) { super(i); }
   public void func() {}
}


public class C extends A {
   public C(int i) { super(i); }
   public void func() {}
}
```

How do I dynamically instantiate company.C or company.B by invoking the constructor function (with a certain integer argument) and invoking the func() method? I know we can use the following [method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructors%28%29) and pass an argument, but not sure how to invoke func() method on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Java Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) .

Answer (score 0):

If your constructor haven't any argument you can do (otherwise read @Adeel link):

```
A myObj = MyClass.newInstance();
```

[Class.newInstance() javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29)